# Translate SQL into hibernate criteria

Tags: mysql, hibernate, criteria

I have a rather complicated sql statement I would like to translate into a criterion in order to add it to my existant criterions.

Here is the SQL statement :

```
 SELECT GREATEST(max(SUBSTRING(numero_facture, 7)), max(SUBSTRING(numero_facture, LENGTH(prefixe)))) FROM facture
```

Is there a way to translate this into a hibernate criteria ?

Thanks !

Comment: To be clear here, you want a criteria query and not just an HQL query?  Handling `GREATEST` is going to be a challenge, as this function is not supported in HQL AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah I already have criterions and I want to add this to the existing Criterions, so not in hql. If GREATEST doesn't exist, all I want to do is to get the max of a substring. The difficulty is that sometimes, prefixe is null, then I can't substring on the length of it but I want to substring from 7.